# How to do HTTPPUT request using XML?

Tags: java, apache, http-put

I am learning rest API and I find it difficult to do the `PUT` request. Below is  the code which I tried. But the record doesn't get updated successfully

The URL used - `http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/PRODUCT/1`

Value trying to update - `<PRICE>24.8</PRICE> to <PRICE>24.9</PRICE>`

Language : Java

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPut putrequest = new HttpPut(
            "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/PRODUCT/1");
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>() {{
        add(new BasicNameValuePair("content-type", "application/xml"));
        add(new BasicNameValuePair("Server", "Apache-Coyote/1.1"));

    }};
    for (NameValuePair h : nvps) {
        putrequest.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }
    String xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><PRODUCT xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\">\n" +
            "    <ID>1</ID>\n" +
            "    <NAME>Chair Shoe</NAME>\n" +
            "    <PRICE>24.9</PRICE>\n" +
            "</PRODUCT>";

    putrequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(xml));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putrequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

I get the `500` response but I am able to add the record if the record is not there using `HTTPPUT`. How to fix this?

Comment: Thanks Ram , let me follow the same in future

Comment: Please edit the question and add details like what you have searched so far and tried any ways to solve it and what problems you faced. This might help readers to answer your question.

Comment: Which verison of REST or which REST jar was used?

Answer (score 0):

If it's getting added and still you are getting 500, then there are below possibilities:

1. Server encounter error after records getting added
2. server side code is wrongly put the STATUS code